# Stateful Firewall

Tags: networking, firewall

I am a beginner in firewall and trying my hands on stateful firewall rules. I do understand that with stateful rules, the first packet is inspected as per the rules but subsequent packets that belong to the same connection are passed without any checks.

But I didnt really understand the states NEW ESTABLISHED RELATED. For instance if i want a stateful firewall which of these states I should include in the rule?

```
-A INPUT -m conntract --ctstate ESTABLISHED,NEW -j ACCEPT
```

What will the above rule do in context of these states?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

State NEW represent the first packet (TCP Sync), usually specify the condition such as IP or port to allow pass through.  ESTABLISHED represent all sequence packets (IP & Port reversed) for the same connection, usually didn't need to specify any condition because it is based on the NEW packet.  RELATED represent return packets for specific protocols such as ICMP echo reply.

So a typical iptables entries are like below.  There might be many NEW entries but normally one RELATED,ESTABLISHED entry is enough.

```
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
```